# Where can I ask about a company's business model and decisions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where on Stack Exchange can I ask the following question?

> Why does Google want to make money from YouTube through ads?

Comment: Might be worth asking on [Economics Meta](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/) whether this kind of question would be OK.

Comment: @RobertLongson, why the Meta?

Comment: in case its not ok. Better to check on meta and check if its on topic/in scope rather than just go in posts blazing...

Comment: If you do decide to go ahead, any question you post on SE will have to show some attempt at research. At least explain why you are asking, and possibly, provide some context. If your question consists of a single line, it's pretty certain it will get closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not sure, especially if it is not specific to a site, you can ask on their Meta site to check its suitability and relevance to the site's scope.

The best site for this question is probably:

> [Economics Meta](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/)
>
> Economics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those who study, teach, research and apply economics and econometrics.

Comment: Before you post on a (non-meta) Stack Exchange site, it's also worth checking the `/help/on-topic` page ("What topics can I ask about here?") in the Help Center for that site; most sites have customized that page to indicate what kinds of questions are and aren't allowed on the site. For instance, [here's a link to that help page on Economics.SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).